# Como retirar a seleção de um TListBox

Tags: delphi

Estou criando um componente para servir como refinamento para pesquisas, oferecendo sugestões. Esse componente tem um TEdit onde pode-se informar o que se deseja pesquisar, uma lista onde os valores possíveis para sugestão são armazenados e um TListBox para apresentar as sugestões.

Tenho uma classe que herda da classe TWinControl, que por sua vez tem 2 subcomponentes: (i) um TEdit; (ii) e um TListBox. Ao editar o TEdit o TListBox é atualizado apresentando apenas os valores que combinam com o valor do TEdit. É possível ainda selecionar um valor do TListBox para que o TEdit seja preenchido com esse valor.

A minha duvida (E problema) está na saída do TListBox. Quando o foco sai do TListBox, nenhum dos valores deve permanecer selecionado, onde o usuário pode também voltar ao TEdit (Inclusive com a seta para cima). Na saída desse componente estou utilizando `ItemIndex := -1;`. Isso funciona, porém quando utilizo a tecla para cima, o foco vai para o TEdit, e os itens do TListBox são desmarcados, só que em algum momento o primeiro item é selecionado novamente, e não sei o porque nem como corrigir ou contornar isso. Caso eu utilize o mouse para sair do TListBox e ir ao TEdit a lista tem os valores desmarcados e funciona corretamente, sem marcar nenhum valor novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Basta no evento `OnExit()` do seu ListBox você fazer o seguinte código:

```
ListBox1.ClearSelection;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Já tentei essa solução e não funcionou. O que é estranho é que quando saio clicando com o mouse, ele passa pelo evento `OnExit()` e quando visualizo o formulário não há nenhum item selecionado. Quando saio com a seta pra cima, indo para o mesmo TEdit, ele passa pelo evento `OnExit()`, e realmente os itens são desmarcados. Porém quando visualizo o formulário o primeiro item esta selecionado, visualmente e nas propriedades.

Comment: Estranho, porque testei aqui e funcionou, a menos que existam verificações a mais no seu código. Debugue e verifique o motivo disso estar acontecendo.

Comment: Mesmo voltado pela seta para cima? Eu tenho um evento um evento `OnKeyDown()` que verifica quando for a seta para cima, seto o foco para o TEdit.